# rpm + rpm -ba Build the source

Tags: linux

When I perfrom `rpm -ba /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/my_spec.spec` the output does not include the `Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/SRPMS/test.sh-6.2-2.rpm`

`/usr/src/redhat/RPMS` does not show the `test.sh-6.2-2.rpm`

```
 [root@linux /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES]#  rpm -ba   /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/my_spec.spec
 Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /var/tmp/test.sh
 Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/SRPMS/test.sh-6.2-2.src.rpm
```

Spec file

```
Summary: An example tool. To show a simple rpm build of the tool.
Name: test.sh
Version: 6.2
Release: 2
Source:/root/test.sh
Group: Development/Debuggers
BuildRoot:/var/tmp/test.sh
License: OtherLicense
%description
```

Answer (score 0):

rpmbuild will not create a RPM that contains no files. Did you forget the `%files` section?

Comment: please advice how to add this to the spec file , did I need also to add the test.sh file path , and how to the spec file?

Comment: If the tutorial you're using doesn't cover this then it's time to find a new tutorial.